# I don't know what the problem is, but some apps look weird like this [SOLVED]

Tags: gtk

i've install audacity from flatpak source, and this happen...

[image]

and install Telegram Desktop from flatpak, and this happen when browse files.. can anyone tell me what wrong?

[image]

Comment: Advice: install apps from appcenter ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of the double window I don't understand well the reason why it happens, but it is solved by editing the direct access to the application.

This command must be included:

`GTK_CSD=0`

I will show you an example of how i edit PlayOnLinux application:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=PlayOnLinux
GenericName=Game
Comment=PlayOnLinux
Type=Application
Exec=env GTK_CSD=0 playonlinux% F
Icon=playonlinux
Categories=Game;
```

It is necessary to edit the file as administrator. generally the accesses to the application are in:

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

To open the "files" application as an administrator you must right-click and choose to open as administrator

Source: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/244

The second problem seems to be related to the fonts, you could try to get that fonts is the one used by the application and install it. or if the application allows it, you could change the fonts from the configuration of the application.

if this solves your question don't forget to mark as solved